# rails way user to user messaging, do I need a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Quick question (I think). I have users, and I would like to allow them to send messages to one another.  My question is, should I have a user table, a message table, and a users to messages join table, or should I just store to_user_id and from_user_id in the messages table.  If the latter, what would the association look like for that?  Can you even reference a 'local' key for an association?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a couple of simple `has_many` associations. Since it's self-referential, you'll need to override some of the Rails magic to make it work.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  has_many :received_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

Rails doesn't have a cleaner way to doing self-referential associations that I know of.

Comment: this does work correctly, thank you i will be implementing it.  i am still curious as to whether this is the railsiest way to do this?

Comment: also, if there were a different key than sender_id and recipient_id that you wanted to reference in Message, is there some fancy tricky way to define a "local" key?

Comment: @re5et Yes, that would be `:primary_key`

Answer (score 0):

I think the latter sounds fine.  This is just off the top of my head but I know AR's associations have options like this...

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => :user, :foreign_key => :from_user_id
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => :user, :foreign_key => :to_user_id
  #...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :received_messages, :class_name => :message, :foreign_key => :to_user_id
  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => :message, :foreign_key => :from_user_id
end
```

Comment: the belongs_to associations in Message here won't work, right? Those keys are not foreign, but are local to Message.